# Create macOS script to run a Terminal Command

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line

I want to ultimately create an executable file that will run a terminal command:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

I want to know what other text and where to add into the Script Editor with the above command so I can create an executable file that runs that command. I would like to do it with out the Terminal window opening. But if it has to open, I would like to add some more code so that is closes.

If there isn't, there should be a Chrome extension that does this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `do shell script` *command*, however, I've changed the *double-quotes* to *single-quotes* in the `open` *command*, so as not to have to escape them with a *backslash* character.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
do shell script "open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory='Guest Profile'"
```

You can save this as an **AppleScript** *application*.

Note that if **Google Chrome** might already be running and you want to be switching to e.g. **Guest Profile**, then change the `-a` *option* of the `open` *command* to: `-na`

---

On my system it opens **Google Chrome** with the following dialog box:

[image]

Comment: Great. This totally worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

While user3439894 has provided the correct [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414616/create-macos-script-to-run-a-terminal-command/414618#414618) to your question, I would like to point out a simpler solution would be to use the Automator to create an application. Here you would not have to wrap the `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Guest Profile"` command in `do shell script`. The steps are given below.

1. Open the Automator application.
2. In the window shown below, choose `Application`.

   [image]
3. Highlight `Utilities` under `Library`, then drag and drop `Run Shell Script` as show below.

   [image]
4. Enter your command, as shown below.

   [image]
5. Save as an Application. Below is an example.

   [image]
6. Quit the Automator application.

### (Optional) Changing the Icon

I do not have Chrome installed, so I will use Safari for this example.

1. Do a `Get Info` on both `Safari.app` and `Guest Chrome.app`. The following will be displayed.

   [image]
2. Drag and drop, the larger Safari icon on to the smaller Automator icon, as shown below.

   [image]
3. The result is shown below. Close both windows.

   [image]

Comment: As I stated, I do not have Chrome installed. I used Safari just as an example. If you add how to to your answer, I will remove it from my answer.